# how to use hystrix to monitoring all microservices

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, hystrix

I'm new on microservices and I have seen a tutorial(from udemy) where shows technologies like eureka, feign,spring cloud config,hystrix and zuul, but after make some examples I don't understand very well how hystrix monitor and zuul works, In the examples I noticed that hystrix is used by a main application that it access to microservices and in that way I can monitoring my microservices, but with zuul I noticed that it works like a proxy but this is calling the same microservices like the other application, so my question is how can I monitoring the microservices with hystrix if are called by zuul and by the another application, am I need two hystrix monitor or can I have one general?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After read some examples I noticed that zuul is always the start for applications so I can add hystrix monitor to zuul and call the microservices, but I still have doubt about the circuit breaker in use with zuul so I will keep searching.